# Как получить message.text в html

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Есть бот, который делает описание к альбому медиа файлов. Когда я ему отправляю сообщение(описание), он его присваивать к описанию альбома. Если отправить сообщение с жирным текстом, то он присвоит его в обычном тексте. Как сохранить шрифт при получении сообщения message.text

Answer (score 1):

узнать стиль отправленного сообщения боту можно с помощью [`entities`](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#working-with-entities):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_handler(message):
    print(message.entities[0].type)
```

- bold - жирный шрифт
- italic - курсив
- underline - подчёркнутый
- strikethrough - зачёркнутый
- code - моноширинный